# If the integral of a function is positive then the function is positive?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a integrable function. I know if $ f> 0 $ then
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\; dx >0.$$ The converse is true? That is, if $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\; dx >0$$ then $f>0$?
I couldn't think of an example that makes it false the converse.

Comment: Draw some pictures

Comment: All you can conclude is that there is exists some sub-interval $[c, d] \subseteq [a, b] $ with $c<d$ such that $f>0$ on $[c, d] $. So a positive integral means that the function must be positive on some non-degenerate sub-interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^3x\,\mathrm dx$, which happens to be equal to $4$?

Comment: Yes I agree. But I want to know if the result is valid in general.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno If there is _any_ counterexample, then the result isn't valid in general.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: a single example is enough to prove that the general case does not hold !

Comment: Yes of course. Sorry, I had misunderstood the answer.

Comment: And if $a\geq 0$?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno Take the integral of $(x-2)$ from $1$ to $5$, say.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno You can also easily find examples with $f(a)\gt 0$ and $f(b)\gt 0$, incidentally, by taking a quadratic that starts high enough and then dips below zero; for instance, $\int_a^b(x-(a+b)/2)^2-\epsilon\ dx$ for some small enough $\epsilon$.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: the signs of $a,b$ play absolutely no role: you can translate everything freely along $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any function that is negative. Say $-1$ from $0$ to $1$. Compensate by a larger positive area, say $+1$ from $1$ to $2$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not restrict $f$ to be non negative,take $f=2\chi_{(1,2]} - \chi_{[0,1)}$ on $[0,2]$.Otherwise,even if you restrict $f$ to be non negative,this is not always the case.For example,$f=\chi_{(0,1]}$ on $[0,1]$.If you want a general answer in terms of the Lebesgue integral,it's true that on a measure space $X$, if the integral of a non negative measurable function $f$ is zero,then $f=0$ almost everywhere.You can prove this quite easily with Markov's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

What does $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\; dx >0$  show?....It says that the area covered by above x-axis is more that area covered by the part below x-axis.

For eg. a function which is always positive will always lie above the x-axis, so the area above x-axis will be always more that below (which will be zero here).

eg. $f(x) = (x-3)^2 +2 $

[image]

But the fact that the integral is positive does not mean that the function is positive, as it could also mean that the area above the x-axis is more. So portion of the function could exist below graph in such a condition, provided  that its area under  is less that the part above.

eg. $f(x) = x(x-3)(x-5)$ from $x=0.5$ to $x=3.5$

[image]

Here the portion (1) which is above the x-axis is definitely larger than the portion (2) below x-axis. So the definite integral will be positive here, but notice how the function is also negative .